# How to convert gpg4win's ascii to binary?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

`gpg4win` can save and read encrypted files in two forms:

1. Binary with `.gpg` extension
2. Base64/ascii with `.asc` extension

Is there a way to convert the Base64/ascii output to binary?
I tried with Notepad++ option "Base64 Decode" but that doesn't work:

[image]

**Note:**
I am not trying to decrypt, just convert from ascii to binary.
I can successfully do the opposite, i.e. convert gpg4win's binary to ascii by using Notepad++ command "Base64 Encode". gpg4win can decrypt this converted version (of course it can also decrypt the original binary format).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Base64 (or ASCII armor) option produces two separate base64 outputs. The first is the base64 encoding of the ciphertext. After that is the base64 encoding of a checksum, and this line is preceded with an equal sign. This encoding is specified in the [OpenPGP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6). And of course, the base64 chunks are surrounded with the obvious header and footer lines, e.g. for my gpg program the output starts out with

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Comment: GPGTools - http://gpgtools.org
```

and ends with

```
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

I don't have Notepad++ but you should just be able to delete the header and footer lines *and* the checksum line and then base64 decode what remains to have a viable binary OpenPGP-compliant file.

Comment: How can I thank you my dear. You have answered my question :) I am so grateful to you, really, thank so much!!

Comment: Hi James Polk. I have some follow-ups questions please: https://superuser.com/questions/1374910/is-gpgwin-the-best-way-to-protect-text-file

Comment: Hi James, can you help doing the reverse please? https://superuser.com/questions/1375379/how-to-convert-gpg4wins-binary-to-ascii-with-notepad

Comment: @get_going: If this answer is correct then please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I just did that. Sorry I am new so didn't know what to do, thanks for telling me. Can you help me do the reverse please? See link in my previous comment.