# How to convert gpg4win's binary to ascii, with Notepad++

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, openpgp, gpg4win

I can reliably convert gpg4win's ascii to binary using Notepad++ option "Base64 Decode" (credit: James K Polk). Works every time.

But when I attempt the reverse, i.e. convert binary to ascii, it works sometimes and does not work other times. Here's how I'm doing it:

- Open the binary file in Notepad++ and select "Base64 Encode".
- Manually add the BEGIN/END PGP message lines (-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----)

This works sometimes (i.e. gpg4win can decrypt the resulting file), but fails other times (gpg4win can't decrypt). I am careful to do it exactly the same way each time, making sure there are no white spaces, etc. But it only works sometimes.

How can I get it to work using Notepad++?

**Note:**
I can do the conversion using --enarmor, but I would like to be able to do it with Notepad++. Especially since I can get it to work sometimes, so I know it's possible, and maybe I'm missing a small piece.

Comment: With this approach I think you are having difficulties with characters that Notepad++ understands as end-of-line. I don't think this is viable.

Comment: I don't have access to a windows environment so I can't test gpg4win or Notepad++. However, using gpg I have verified that 1) gpg ignores whitespace **except** that the `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----` must end in a newline and the `-----END PGP MESSAGE-----` must be preceded by a newline. 2) You don't need a comment line, but if you do have one it must be terminated by a newline. 3) You don't need a checksum line, but if you have one it must be preceded by a newline and it must be the correct checksum.

Comment: @james-k-polk. Hi James, I could get certutil and even openssl to work (had to add the BEGIN/END lines manually), but Notepad++ doesn't work for encoding. It's works every time for decoding though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ is an editor for text files, which are files that end with special
binary characters that denote an end-of-line.
It will always think that your text-line is found between two end-of-line
characters, and will mostly ignore the end-of-line itself in its operations.

This has the potential to destroy the file when converting to Base64,
since Notepad++ will convert the text between the end-of-lines, but may
cause a problem with not correctly handling the end-of-lines.

In fact, it's pretty amazing for me that this has worked correctly for you
for some files, and I can readily understand that it didn't for others.

I think you should really look for another solution than Notepad++ for
converting to Base64.

Comment: After some more attempts I found something interesting. If I decrypt the Base64 encoded *file*, I get an error (https://i.imgur.com/jcD4n1b.jpg). BUT, If I copy the contents of the file directly into gpg4win's notepad, it works.

Comment: You found a method of circumventing the end-of-line problem? I don't know gpg4win so cannot explain why it works.

Comment: No I didn't. I just described what I observed, i.e. if I open the Base64 encoded file and copy the contents to gpg4win's notepad, it can decrypt. So I know Notepad++ is doing something right. But if I ask gpg4win to decrypt the file itself, it fails. What reliable alternative you can recommend on Windows?

Comment: Microsoft#s [certutil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil) can do that (and much more), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16946681/165358) for a description. There are many others floating around like [this one](http://www.proxoft.com/base64.aspx).

Comment: certutil worked. I encoded many encrypted binary files to base64 using certutil and gpgwin decoded them fine. Worked every time. So I am surprised. Notepadd++ can decode base64 to binary just fine (worked every time), but it can't do the reverse even though the "Base64 Encode" is right there.

Comment: Hi harrymc, your answer gave me an alternative. I tried openssl and that works too. But I was interested in getting this to work with Notepad++. I believe this should work because there's specific options for it (screen shot: https://i.imgur.com/DrWhIlR.jpg). I'll wait some more to see if there's a way to get Notepad++ to work, then I'll mark your answer as Accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Without thorough investigation, you could say that opening a binary file in a text editor and using a plug-in that expects ascii input is an unreliable solution. I would use `gpg --enarmor`. `certutil` generates `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` which will prevent gpg from working.

Comment: @evpo. Hi evpo, I tested your method (--enarmor) and it is the best. I don't manually have to remove the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and replace with -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----. I see that you are the author or Encryptpad? Will you add Base64/ascii to your program please?

Comment: yes, many people ask for it: 
https://github.com/evpo/EncryptPad/issues/9
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/encryptpad/BXDQeGXmJeY